# Instructing Python to click a button using urllib2

Tags: javascript, python, csv, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm writing a web scraper using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup in python and am looking for a way to instruct python to click a button on a page that it reads the HTML source code for.

The following snippet of my script reads in URLs from a csv file and is meant to scrape data from the webpages specified, but an intermediary step is to click a "submit" button that exists on the webpage that is read from the csv's provided URLs.

```
for line in triplines:
    FromTo = line.split(",")
    From = FromTo[0].strip()
    print(From)
    To = FromTo[1].strip()
    print(To)
    url = KCString1 + From + KCString2 + To + KCString3
    print(url)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    page_source = page.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
    print(soup.prettify())
```

Is there a way to utilize urllib2 functionality in such a way as to say "follow the URL that is obtained from clicking *this* button"? I imagine I may need to find the JavaScript source to identify the button's identifiers first.

Comment: Why not using Scrapy (http://scrapy.org/)?

Comment: Not sure if you want to use urllib2 for this. Have you looked at [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)?

Answer (score 3):

Buttons do not typically have urls attached to them. They normally need javascript interaction, which needs emulation. If you want to click a button, you should use a browser emulator like [Ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py) instead of a parser like Beautifulsoup